# convert string in a field name rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

a need how convert string value in field name valid:

Example:

> <%="price.list_"+current_user.price.to_s%>

so

> price.list_1

then is my real field name. this name.this field will use it to do more operations in my view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I understood your question. You will need to use the send function

```
<%= price.send("list_#{current_user.price}".to_sym) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

That should work but you can also do

```
<%= "price.list_#{current_user.price.to_s}" %>
```

**OR**

```
<p>
  price.list_<%= current_user.price.to_s %>
</p>
```

**UPDATE:** I misunderstood the question. This is going to require some Javascript or AJAX, depending on your exact application.

**JS:**

```
:onchange => 'update(this.value)'

function update(new_value) {
  var update_me = document.getElementById('update_this_field');
  update_me.value = new_value;
}
```

**AJAX on RAILS**

```
:onchange => remote_function(:url => {:action => 'update'}, :with => 'Form.element.serialize(this)'), :name => 'foo'

def update
  bar = params[:foo]
  render :update do |page|
    page.replace_html 'update_this_field', "price.list_" + bar
  end
end
```

Comment: Also, typically, people assign **@current_user**, so make sure you got that right.

Comment: thanks @Kyle Macey, but I still prints "price.list_1", not the value in the field

Comment: I'm sorry, I just need to print multiple columns generating each column name dynamically. price.list_1 is the name of a column but change according to the registered user so as to "current_user.price"in this case has the value 1 if concatenate "price.list_" + current_user.price.to_s, I generated price . list_1 is correct, but it generated string name, not the value within price.list_1 it would be 56.02 for example, hope I've explained and apology

Comment: So does column price have an attirbute like "amount"? Because then it would be current_user.price.amount.to_s